# Integrating factor for non-exact differential

Tags: differential-forms

Given $\frac{xdy+ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ I took partials of either coefficient wrt to other variable I get $\partial P/\partial y$ as $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and $\partial Q/\partial x$ as $\frac{-x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and as these aren't equal it isnt exact.

However when i try find an integrating factor that is a only dependent on one of the variables i get a contradiction.

Can i just use inspection and say that $\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{xy}$ would work?

Comment: Whether you can "just use inspection" is a question of your instructor's expectations.

Comment: We weren't explicitly taught it, but the question just asks me to find one without stipulating how.

Comment: are you sure i've made a mistake? Ive just double checked them and got the same results.

Comment: In the way ive written out the question i've written it as Qdy+Pdx as that the order in the question even though its not conventional, i checked and Pdy + Qdx (same P and Q) which is exact.

Comment: You're right -- I was being careless; sorry. A simple way to deal with this form is to notice that the numerator is exact, so you can just take the denominator as an integrating factor.